# calling JS to custom menu design

Tags: menus, jquery, javascript

I have designed a custom menu of the form:

```
<nav class="content">
    <ul class="exo-menu">
        <li><a class="active menhome" href="/"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
        <li class="mega-drop-down"><a href="#" onclick="return false"><i class="fa"></i> Brands</a>
            <div id="wrapper" class="animated fadeIn mega-menu hidden">
                <div class="mega-menu-wrap">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                        <!-- Tab panes -->
                            <div class="tab-content">
                                <div class="tab-pane active" id="Featured">
                                    <ul class="nav-list list-inline list-inline2">
                                        <li><a data-filter=".89" href="/brand/allmax-nutrition/"><img src="https://i0.wp.com/www.mysite.co.uk/wp-content/themes/mysite/images/image.png" alt="image"><span></span></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="AtoF">
                                    <ul class="nav-list list-inline col-md-2">                                
                                        <li><a href="/brand/brand1/"><span>BRAND 1</span></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="GtoN">
                                    <ul class="nav-list list-inline col-md-2">
                                        <li><a href="/brand/brand2/"><span>BRAND 2E</span></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="OtoW">
                                    <ul class="nav-list list-inline col-md-2">                                                                            
                                        <li><a href="/brand/brand3/"><span>BRAND 3</span></a></li>
                                    </ul>                          
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Nav tabs -->
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">   
                            <li   class="active change"><a href="#Featured" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Featured</a></li>
                            <li class="change"><a href="#AtoF" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"># - F</a></li>
                            <li class="change"><a href="#GtoN" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">G - N</a></li>
                            <li class="change"><a href="#OtoW" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">O - Z</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="mega-drop-down mega-drop-down-2"><a href="#" onclick="return false"><i class="fa"></i> CATEGORIES</a>
            <div id="wrapper2" class="animated fadeIn mega-menu mega-menu2 hidden">
                <div class="mega-menu-wrap">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                        <!-- Tab panes -->
                            <div class="tab-content">
                                <div class="tab-pane active">
                                    <ul class="nav-list list-inline col-lg-12">
                                    </ul>
                                </div>    
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </li>               
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I have included below this, some JS which adds to its functionality:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
            $('.toggle-menu').click(function (){
            $('.exo-menu').toggleClass('display');

            });
        });
        jQuery(document).ready( function ( $ ){
            $(".change>a").hover( function () { 
                $(this)[0].click();
            }, 
            function () {
            /* code for mouseout */
            });
        }); 

        var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("mega-drop-down, drop-down");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
            acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
        panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } 
    else {
        panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }    
}
}
</script>
```

I would like to take the JS and make a js file which I can link t this menu.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Surely.

```
function loadMenuScripts()
{
        wp_enqueue_script( 'main', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/main.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', false );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'loadMenuScripts' );
```

Additionally, if you need to load it in the footer, go ahead and change the action to:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'loadMenuScripts' );
```

Also, it seems as if this is an option for users.

Before enqueueing, check to see if your menu is being used:

```
if( class_exists( 'mega_menu` ) ) {
    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'loadMenuScripts' ); // Or whatever.
}
```

So you don't enqueue it if it's not necessary.

In fact, I'd recommend you create a Class for this functionality and then decide, based on whether or not this Mega Menu is enabled, to enqueue its assets.